# Create pageable JDBC source for Flink Job

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-sql

For processing data from DB I am using flink. I have created input with jdbc.

```
val inputFormat = JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
             .setDrivername(driver)
             .setDBUrl(url)
             .setUsername(username)
             .setPassword(password)
             .setQuery("select id, name from users")
             .finish()

env.createInput(inputFormat)
```

The issue is that this input is getting all data from table. Since this table contains huge amount of information I need something like pageable jdbc source. Is there any additional setting I can use for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split a query in to multiple partial which are independently executed by specifying the query as a parameterized query and providing values to bind against the parameter(s).

The following is taken from the JavaDoc of [`JDBCInputFormat`](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.10/flink-connectors/flink-jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/io/jdbc/JDBCInputFormat.java).

```
 * <p>In order to query the JDBC source in parallel, you need to provide a
 * parameterized query template (i.e. a valid {@link PreparedStatement}) and
 * a {@link ParameterValuesProvider} which provides binding values for the
 * query parameters. E.g.:
 *
 * <pre><code>
 *
 * Serializable[][] queryParameters = new String[2][1];
 * queryParameters[0] = new String[]{"Kumar"};
 * queryParameters[1] = new String[]{"Tan Ah Teck"};
 *
 * JDBCInputFormat jdbcInputFormat = JDBCInputFormat.buildJDBCInputFormat()
 *              .setDrivername("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver")
 *              .setDBUrl("jdbc:derby:memory:ebookshop")
 *              .setQuery("select * from books WHERE author = ?")
 *              .setRowTypeInfo(rowTypeInfo)
 *              .setParametersProvider(new GenericParameterValuesProvider(queryParameters))
 *              .finish();
 * </code></pre>
```

Note that:

- The queried table should have an appropriate index on the parameterized attribute. Otherwise, you will do several full scans on over the table, which is not helpful.
- The parameters should cover all (required) data of the table just once. Otherwise you might miss some rows or query some rows twice.